# Angular error - Type 'Response' is not generic

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get a nested array from an http response using Angular 14

```
getItems(): Observable<Item[]>
{
    return this._httpClient.get<Item[]>(this.apiUrl + 'items').pipe(
        tap((items) => {
            this._items.next(items);
        })
    ).pipe(
        map((res: Response<Item[]>) => {
            res = res.array1;
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```

but get error on

```
Response<Item[]>
```

saying:

> Type 'Response' is not generic.ts(2315)

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type provided to the `http.get<T>()` call is not correct. It should match the shape returned by your api. So if your response shape looks like this:

```js
interface GetItemsResponse {
   array1: Item[]
}
```

Then you should indicate that type on your `get` call:

```js
getItems(): Observable<Item[]>
{
    return this._httpClient.get<GetItemsResponse>(this.apiUrl + 'items').pipe(
        map((res: GetItemsResponse) => res.array1),
        tap((items: Items[]) =>  this._items.next(items))
    );
}
```

Also, you don't need to specify the types in the operators, typescript will correctly infer them:

```js
getItems(): Observable<Item[]>
{
    return this._httpClient.get<GetItemsResponse>(this.apiUrl + 'items').pipe(
        map(res => res.array1),                // res is type GetItemsResponse
        tap(items =>  this._items.next(items)) // items is type Item[]
    );
}
```

Comment: You're right, I just wonder if Angular no more uses "Response" type to map the http responses ?